# Android Studio: Java: Populating 2D Array with buttons using IDs

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I am trying to populate a 2d array with buttons for the purpose of creating a tic tac toe type of game, that is 5x5 in size.

So far I have come up with this: (Not working)

```
private Button[][] gameArray = new Button[5][5];
for (int x = 0; x<5; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; x < 5; y++) {
          String gameButtonId = "buttons" + x + y;
          int gameID = getResources().getIdentifier(gameButtonId, "id", getPackageName());
          gameArray[x][y] = findViewById(gameID);
          gameArray[x][y].setOnClickListener(this);
```

I have created the buttons with specific ids as follows:
the first row has button ids: buttons00, buttons01, buttons02, buttons03, buttons04,
the second row is: buttons10, buttons11, buttons12, buttons 13, buttons14 and so on.. until there is 25 buttons on the grid.

How would I effectively populate the 2d array using these buttons and their ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner- loop is wrong! You're running until `x < 5`, but it should be `y < 5` instead!

Your code should look like this:

```
private Button[][] gameArray = new Button[5][5];
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
          String gameButtonId = "buttons" + x + y;
          int gameID = getResources().getIdentifier(gameButtonId, "id", getPackageName());
          gameArray[x][y] = findViewById(gameID);
          gameArray[x][y].setOnClickListener(this);
```